# How to remove a TextField from ListView when onPressed button?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove the TextField when user click on "clear icon" button ? (not just clear the Text of TextField)

**User Story** 
The user click on a button to add player. (Technically this button add TextField) 
The user can write the name of player on TextField.
The user click on a "clear icon" button to remove current TextField (opposite of add function).

[image]

```
new ListView.builder(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        print(index);
                        return TextField(
                          maxLength: 20,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Player ${index+1}",
                            counterText: "",
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                            suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                onPressed: () =>
                                  setState(() {
                                    this.dispose(); // -----Doesn't work----
                                  })
                                ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
```

For example, user set "John" on Player 4 if user click on "clear button" then Player 4 TextField is deleted. It will remain only 4 TextField

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Facts I assume:**

1. you want to be able to delete (or add) a field from (to) the list
2. you want the values of the remaining fields to remain when you delete the field
3. the list can be larger than 5

**Solution:**

If you want all the above to be true, then you actually need to track the `TextEditingController`s of the TextFields, instead of the text fields themselves. This is because the value of the TextField is actually stored in the TextEditingController (which is created anew on the fly if you do not supply it for each widget). Check this out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// needs to be StatefulWidget, so we can keep track of the count of the fields internally
class PlayerList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerList({
    this.initialCount = 5,
  });

  // also allow for a dynamic number of starting players
  final int initialCount;

  @override
  _PlayerListState createState() => _PlayerListState();
}

class _PlayerListState extends State<PlayerList> {
  int fieldCount = 0;
  int nextIndex = 0;
  // you must keep track of the TextEditingControllers if you want the values to persist correctly
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = <TextEditingController>[];

  // create the list of TextFields, based off the list of TextControllers
  List<Widget> _buildList() {
    int i;
    // fill in keys if the list is not long enough (in case we added one)
    if (controllers.length < fieldCount) {
      for (i = controllers.length; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        controllers.add(TextEditingController());
      }
    }

    i = 0;
    // cycle through the controllers, and recreate each, one per available controller
    return controllers.map<Widget>((TextEditingController controller) {
      int displayNumber = i + 1;
      i++;
      return TextField(
        controller: controller,
        maxLength: 20,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Player $displayNumber",
          counterText: "",
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              // when removing a TextField, you must do two things:
              // 1. decrement the number of controllers you should have (fieldCount)
              // 2. actually remove this field's controller from the list of controllers
              setState(() {
                fieldCount--;
                controllers.remove(controller);
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(); // convert to a list
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // generate the list of TextFields
    final List<Widget> children = _buildList();

    // append an 'add player' button to the end of the list
    children.add(
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // when adding a player, we only need to inc the fieldCount, because the _buildList()
          // will handle the creation of the new TextEditingController
          setState(() {
            fieldCount++;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text(
              'add player',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // build the ListView
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: children,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // upon creation, copy the starting count to the current count
    fieldCount = widget.initialCount;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(PlayerList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
}
```

With the above, you can:

- start the app
- change player 2 to 'bob'
- change player 3 to 'steve'
- change player 4 to 'charles'
- delete player 3
- observe that player 2 is 'bob' and the new player 3 is 'charles'

I think this is what you are looking for here.

Comment: thx you very much for your help and your answer well explained :)

Comment: I tried to do this: Scrolling automatically to bottom page  when user click on "add player" button. I added a ScrollController but doesn't work
`ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
   if (controllers.length < fieldCount) {
      for (i = controllers.length; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        controllers.add(TextEditingController());
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          0.0,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        );
      }
    }`

Comment: your scroll controller needs to be a variable that is not recreated during each redraw. you need to make it a property of the `_PlayerListState` class, and initialize it only in the `initState()` function. then attach it as the controller for the `ListView` in the `_buildList()` function. then doing your `_scrollController.animateTo()` should work, but only if you put it inside the `onTap` callback. move it there to avoid errors about `setState()` during build phase.

Comment: I don't understand what i have to do: "then attach it as the controller for the ListView in the _buildList() function" because there aren't ListView in _buildList().
I did: `ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();` in _PlayerListState class.
`_scrollController = ScrollController();` in initState() function.
`controller: _scrollController,` in ListView

Comment: Good answer but isn't it good practice to call .dispose() on each controller in the dispose() override function?

Comment: If a controller is removed does it still need to be disposed() of?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property to check wheter the user clicked that button and depending on the value you show/hide the `TextField`. Below I just use a boolean property if user click on X button then I set `hideField` to true and the `TextField` will be replaced with a zero sized widget.

```
 new ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print(index);
                      bool hideField = false; // I added it here

                      return hideField ? SizedBox.shrink() : TextField(
                        maxLength: 20,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Player ${index + 1}",
                          counterText: "",
                          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                          suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  setState(() {
                                    hideField = true; // Now it works
                                  })
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                )
```

Comment: this will have two problems. 1. you can only have 5 textfields ever, 2. when you remove one of the fields, the values of the others will not persist in the proper order.

Comment: Nope, there will have no problem.

1. Note that I'm just updating the state of the current TextField
2.  The value of others will persist because I'm not rebuilding the while ListView, I'm just replacing the TextField with a widget with zero size.

Comment: plug it into a simulator. the two problems i point out are actual problems.