# How can I handle a widget dynamically created in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a widget like this image  bellow  but i get the error :

```
    Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#
```

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: _buildBar(context),
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("Continue"),
                value: isContinue,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    isContinue = newValue;
                    if (isContinue == true) isClose = false;
                  });
                },
                controlAffinity:
                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
              ),
            
              CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("Fermé"),
                value: isClose,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    isClose = newValue;
                    if (isClose == true) isContinue = false;
                  });
                },
                controlAffinity:
                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
              ),

              PlayerList(getHoraireDay,
                  isClose: isClose, isContinue: isContinue)
            ]
               
            ),
```

Also, do you have any idea how can I add and delete the line dynamically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to set `CheckboxListTile` width, you can use `Expanded flex` 
I do not have code of `PlayerList` but the idea is the same

To add and delete the line dynamically, you can use `ListView.builder` and change `itemCount`
You can reference this [How to remove a TextField from ListView when onPressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386039/how-to-remove-a-textfield-from-listview-when-onpressed-button)

code snippet

```
Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text("Continue"),
...                   
Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text("Fermé"),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isContinue = false;
  bool isClose = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Next page'),
        ),
        body: Form(
            //key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text("Continue"),
                      value: isContinue,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        /* setState(() {
                          isContinue = newValue;
                          if (isContinue == true) isClose = false;
                        });*/
                      },
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity
                          .leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text("Fermé"),
                      value: isClose,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        /*setState(() {
                          isClose = newValue;
                          if (isClose == true) isContinue = false;
                        });*/
                      },
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity
                          .leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*PlayerList(getHoraireDay,
                      isClose: isClose, isContinue: isContinue)*/
                ]))));
  }
}
```